# Is there a way to update a string in place in rust?

Tags: string, replace, rust

You can also consider this as, is it possible to URLify a string in place in rust?

For example,

```
Problem statement: Replace whitespace with %20
Assumption: String will have enough capacity left to accommodate new characters.

Input: Hello how are you

Output: Hello%20how%20are%20you
```

I know there are ways to do this if we don't have to do this "in place". I am solving a problem that explicitly states that you have to update in place.

If there isn't any safe way to do this, is there any particular reason behind that?

[Edit]

I was able to solve this using `unsafe` approach, but would appreciate a better approach than this. More idiomatic approach if there is.

```
fn space_20(sentence: &mut String) {
  if !sentence.is_ascii() {
    panic!("Invalid string");
  }

  let chars: Vec<usize> = sentence.char_indices().filter(|(_, ch)| ch.is_whitespace()).map(|(idx, _)| idx ).collect();
  let char_count = chars.len();
  if char_count == 0 {
    return;
  }

  let sentence_len = sentence.len();
  sentence.push_str(&"*".repeat(char_count*2)); // filling string with * so that bytes array becomes of required size.

  unsafe {
    let bytes = sentence.as_bytes_mut();

    let mut final_idx = sentence_len + (char_count * 2) - 1;

    let mut i = sentence_len - 1;
    let mut char_ptr = char_count - 1;
    loop {
      if i != chars[char_ptr] {
        bytes[final_idx] = bytes[i];
        if final_idx == 0 {
          // all elements are filled.
          println!("all elements are filled.");
          break;
        }
        final_idx -= 1;

      } else {
        bytes[final_idx] = '0' as u8;
        bytes[final_idx - 1] = '2' as u8;
        bytes[final_idx - 2] = '%' as u8;

        // final_idx is of type usize cannot be less than 0.
        if final_idx < 3 {
          println!("all elements are filled at start.");
          break;
        }

        final_idx -= 3;

        // char_ptr is of type usize cannot be less than 0.
        if char_ptr > 0 {
          char_ptr -= 1;
        }
      }

      if i == 0 {
        // all elements are parsed.
        println!("all elements are parsed.");
        break;
      }

      i -= 1;
    }

  }

}


fn main() {
  let mut sentence = String::with_capacity(1000);
  sentence.push_str("  hello, how are you?");
  // sentence.push_str("hello, how  are you?");
  // sentence.push_str(" hello, how are you? ");
  // sentence.push_str("  ");
  // sentence.push_str("abcd");

  space_20(&mut sentence);
  println!("{}", sentence);
}
```

Comment: I guess you can overwrite the string from right to left, so that the writing pointer will never catch up with the reading pointer.   That's an uncommon use case I guess.

Comment: @L.F. I have attempted something similar, but unfortunately my approach seems to be using `unsafe` approach. Yeah, it is not common use case. I was following a C++ tutorial and tried to implement same in Rust. Since i couldn't I wanted to know the reasoning behind it, if not the solution itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *O*(*n*) solution that neither uses `unsafe` nor allocates (provided that the string has enough capacity), using [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html):

```rust
fn urlify_spaces(text: &mut String) {
    const SPACE_REPLACEMENT: &[u8] = b"%20";

    // operating on bytes for simplicity
    let mut buffer = std::mem::take(text).into_bytes();
    let old_len = buffer.len();

    let space_count = buffer.iter().filter(|&&byte| byte == b' ').count();
    let new_len = buffer.len() + (SPACE_REPLACEMENT.len() - 1) * space_count;
    buffer.resize(new_len, b'\0');

    let mut write_pos = new_len;

    for read_pos in (0..old_len).rev() {
        let byte = buffer[read_pos];

        if byte == b' ' {
            write_pos -= SPACE_REPLACEMENT.len();
            buffer[write_pos..write_pos + SPACE_REPLACEMENT.len()]
                .copy_from_slice(SPACE_REPLACEMENT);
        } else {
            write_pos -= 1;
            buffer[write_pos] = byte;
        }
    }

    *text = String::from_utf8(buffer).expect("invalid UTF-8 during URL-ification");
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=538df62055247894860914a581ee84c5))

Basically, it calculates the final length of the string, sets up a reading pointer and a writing pointer, and translates the string from right to left.  Since `"%20"` has more characters than `" "`, the writing pointer never catches up with the reading pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to do this without `unsafe`?

Yes like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut my_string = String::from("Hello how are you");
    
    let mut insert_positions = Vec::new();
    
    let mut char_counter = 0;
    for c in my_string.chars() {
        if c == ' ' {
            insert_positions.push(char_counter);
            char_counter += 2; // Because we will insert two extra chars here later.
        }
        char_counter += 1;
    }
    
    for p in insert_positions.iter() {
        my_string.remove(*p);
        my_string.insert(*p, '0');
        my_string.insert(*p, '2');
        my_string.insert(*p, '%');
    }
    println!("{}", my_string);
}
```

Here is the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2455b400606059f8a1f9aafe19bea20a).

But should you do it?

As discussed for example [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/cykxz3/how_to_mutate_a_string_while_iterating_over_it/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) this is almost always not the recommended way of doing this, because both [`remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.remove) and [`insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.insert) are `O(n)` operations as noted in the documentation.

## Edit

A slightly better version:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut my_string = String::from("Hello how are you");
    
    let mut insert_positions = Vec::new();
    
    let mut char_counter = 0;
    for c in my_string.chars() {
        if c == ' ' {
            insert_positions.push(char_counter);
            char_counter += 2; // Because we will insert two extra chars here later.
        }
        char_counter += 1;
    }
    
    for p in insert_positions.iter() {
        my_string.remove(*p);
        my_string.insert_str(*p, "%20");
    }
    println!("{}", my_string);
}
```

and the corresponding [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9d11810edea4dda4b7b541e7c15275f).

Comment: This is an O(n^2) implementation of what can be an O(n) operation.

Comment: Actually I think it is even worse, because I am using 3x `insert`, while I could instead just use one `insert_str()` but the code still demonstrates how the requirement of the OP could be fulfilled...

Comment: @TranshapHigsn as stated above this can be done way more efficiently, but it should show the general idea...

Comment: @frankenapps thanks for the reference, i will use it for further optimization.

Comment: @TranshapHigsn Does this really count as "in-place" though?  I don't see the difference between using a `Vec` and allocating a new `String` :D

Comment: @L.F. As per documentation, it seems like that `insert` and `insert_str` both are inserting in-place. Only downside i see is `O(n)` time complexity for every such operation. [insert documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.insert)

Comment: I was referring to `insert_positions`, which is a brand new `Vec` that still requires allocation.  Technically the string is being modified in-place, but the space cost is still O(*n*), which kind of defeats the purpose of an in-place algorithm.  The time complexity is also O(*n* ²), so this algorithm is slow (in theory).  I presented an O(*n*)-time, O(1)-space solution in my answer.  Of course, the actual tradeoff should be determined via benchmarking.